# A unique ID per User / Session in logs on all levels? Log4J?

Tags: jsf, logging, log4j, uniqueidentifier

Well we are doing some performance testing to figure out what steps of our application take how much time. Of course easy to parse / filter logs with regexp are a charm.
To the problem: Our jsf application is split into several projects, which are used by other (non jsf) applications.
My first approach would have been:

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("Service call took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time)+ " JSESSIONID="+CookieUtil.getJsessionId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())) ;
```

(CookieUtil would read the sessionId from the HttpServletRequest)

But... obviously other projects don't like dependencies to JSF libraries, nor to my neat CookieUtil. 
Does log4j provide something? 
Is there another tool / concept for this?

Comment: Are the other projects run in servlet containers? If so you could just change CookieUtil to take an HttpServletRequest instead of FacesContext.

Comment: sadly they are not used in servlet containers

Comment: Crosspost to avoid someone running into the hassle with wrong encoding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071882/filter-with-access-to-request-parameter-in-jsf-facelets-leads-to-wrong-encoding

Comment: good call adding the extra information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could accomplish what you are looking for w/ log4j MDC:
[Log4j MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html)

and using a Servlet Filter similar to this example:
[MDCServletFilter](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/)

Comment: yeah. i was very recently introduced to it by a colleague. It is some sweet sauce.

Comment: there is the alternative in adding some informations of the current running thread without adding code:

`The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/> ` looks like `2011-05-12 11:21:35,880 264509 DEBUG [org.some.package.class] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-5:)`  
Is there a disadvantage in using the thread? probably when a user logs out and the thread gets reused

Comment: The scope of ndc is per thread so in a thread per request idiom the scope would end with the request. thus the thread wouldn't be reused with the same context beyond that request.